# android Color of the cell on Grid View changes on scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

So I have a grid of textViews and consists of 228 cells. If a user clicks on any cell on the grid the color of cell changes.But as soon as I scrolled up or down the color moves to another cells.I used customgridview Adapter . Here's the code of getView() .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   View gridView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fingerprintlayout, null);
    }



    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(gridV[position]);  //Setting the text 

    if(position == getClickedCellPosition()){
     convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //Setting the background color

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it actually move to a different cell value or a different cell in the layout?  The convertView == null code is there to reuse a view if it is available.  So you might set the color for cell 1,1 but when you scroll that view may be reused for 2,1.

One solution to VERIFY this is the problem is to remove the null check and just inflate the layout again.  DO NOT RELEASE YOUR CODE LIKE THIS.  It is inefficient.

What you can do is keep a cache of which cells are highlighted or not.  When getView is called you should reset the background to the default if the cell it represents is not selected or you should highlight it if it is selected.